# how to check controller name before it loaded?

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I am working on a task in which I have used HMVC. In it I have to check each controller name and compare it with database value before it loaded every time.  Is there any way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **hooks** to intercept the execution before a controller is created.
see [Hooks - Extending the Framework Core](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) for details.

This will be executed on every request, so if you really need to compare this with database values, consider using a cache like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to store the database entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to get the controller name:

```
 $this->uri->segment(1);
```

But this won't work if you have controller is in sub folder structure.